# docker cannot start container after reboot use '--restart-always'

Tags: linux, docker

i want to the container auto-start after the computer reboot, so i use '--restart=always' flag, but it don't run as i expected.  when i reboot the system, the container didn't startup.

i'v tried to change the Storage driver from aufs to overlay2, use '-s overlay2', but i didn't help.

```
$ uname  -a
Linux DebianV 4.9.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.2-2 (2017-01-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:44:08 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:44:08 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false

$ docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 2
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: overlay2                                                                                                                                                                                           
 Backing Filesystem: extfs                                                                                                                                                                                         
 Supports d_type: true                                                                                                                                                                                             
 Native Overlay Diff: true                                                                                                                                                                                         
Logging Driver: json-file                                                                                                                                                                                          
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs                                                                                                                                                                                            
Plugins:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 Volume: local                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay                                                                                                                                                                         
Swarm: inactive                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Runtimes: runc                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Default Runtime: runc                                                                                                                                                                                              
Init Binary: docker-init                                                                                                                                                                                           
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e
init version: 949e6fa
Kernel Version: 4.9.0-1-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.708 GiB
Name: DebianV
ID: NISJ:R6JZ:VZNI:YBI7:K4ZQ:AGTR:LYSM:KORT:LQE2:RSG5:AQ6B:IEDP
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 14
 Goroutines: 21
 System Time: 2017-02-07T05:24:11.646839781-05:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

docker command

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name db-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -p 0.0.0.0:3306:3306/tcp mysql:8.0
```

docker log info

```
Feb 07 18:20:25 DebianV systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Feb 07 18:20:25 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:25.678236807-05:00" level=debug msg="Listener created for HTTP on fd ()"
Feb 07 18:20:25 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:25.680978493-05:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 689"
Feb 07 18:20:25 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:25.73650121-05:00" level=debug msg="containerd: read past events" count=0
Feb 07 18:20:25 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:25.736734581-05:00" level=debug msg="containerd: supervisor running" cpus=4 memory=7892 runtime=docker-runc runtimeArgs=[] stateDir="/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd"
Feb 07 18:20:25 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:25.736883058-05:00" level=debug msg="containerd: grpc api on /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.184662338-05:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: containerd health check returned error: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.682885811-05:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: containerd health check returned error: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.685111343-05:00" level=debug msg="Using default logging driver json-file"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.685162198-05:00" level=debug msg="Golang's threads limit set to 56160"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.692662747-05:00" level=debug msg="[graphdriver] trying provided driver: overlay2"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.706786753-05:00" level=debug msg="backingFs=extfs,  projectQuotaSupported=false"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.706818944-05:00" level=debug msg="Using graph driver overlay2"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.760129005-05:00" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Downloads: 3"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.760168524-05:00" level=debug msg="Max Concurrent Uploads: 5"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.797342606-05:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.797592133-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit."
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.797655597-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.797672209-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.798426501-05:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.801134155-05:00" level=debug msg="Loaded container 20b7feb5fd9f9317971ccf0beef82822293064a17ee0253d15f2d28d7701b010"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.802298081-05:00" level=debug msg="Loaded container a1f4d5471b0aaa56df52dda1253cb325477f8f83e7f41a5441b64384d4750471"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.812496877-05:00" level=debug msg="Option Experimental: false"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.812527852-05:00" level=debug msg="Option DefaultDriver: bridge"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.812539738-05:00" level=debug msg="Option DefaultNetwork: bridge"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.841694577-05:00" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.856005602-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait --version]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.857414764-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.869113924-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8 -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.870838360-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.872793309-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D PREROUTING]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.874958085-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.876162603-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -F DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.877293053-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -X DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.878215362-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -F DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.879117490-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -X DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.880245980-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.881168273-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.882179754-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -n -L DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.883202411-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -N DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.884433600-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -n -L DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.885449539-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -N DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.886769951-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -n -L DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.888174540-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -N DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.889467417-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.890676291-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.892376504-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -P FORWARD DROP]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.900192096-05:00" level=debug msg="Did not find any interface with name docker0: Link not found"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.900686508-05:00" level=debug msg="Setting bridge mac address to 02:42:09:8e:c7:3a"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.900747358-05:00" level=debug msg="Assigning address to bridge interface docker0: 172.17.0.1/16"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.900821155-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.903652800-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.908402753-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.909608576-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -I DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.910667632-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.911902773-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.912940558-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.914235636-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.915534854-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.916885890-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.918711320-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.920141785-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.921204395-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.922592836-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.924188236-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.925686674-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.926696577-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.927727203-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.928674510-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.929826720-05:00" level=debug msg="Network (1051b85) restored"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.948430206-05:00" level=debug msg="Allocating IPv4 pools for network bridge (1051b850f6816ed2aee01f557af3d6916f2351af3db10663f7994d3fc3309a20)"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.948744303-05:00" level=debug msg="RequestPool(LocalDefault, 172.17.0.0/16, , map[], false)"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.948808713-05:00" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.1, map[RequestAddressType:com.docker.network.gateway])"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.952487468-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.955374734-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.956724396-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.958499869-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.959668312-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.961694367-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.962988747-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.964140719-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.966230938-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.967920820-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.969579637-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.982011576-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.983855543-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.988900941-05:00" level=debug msg="releasing IPv4 pools from network bridge (1051b850f6816ed2aee01f557af3d6916f2351af3db10663f7994d3fc3309a20)"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.988938606-05:00" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.1)"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.988964218-05:00" level=debug msg="ReleasePool(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16)"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.996004689-05:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.996077622-05:00" level=debug msg="Allocating IPv4 pools for network bridge (5d008ad86bc279feae6bb57a19443068fc5e9bc23894383dbd23d8e552ae4972)"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.996099738-05:00" level=debug msg="RequestPool(LocalDefault, 172.17.0.0/16, , map[], false)"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.996138331-05:00" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.1, map[RequestAddressType:com.docker.network.gateway])"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.996338899-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.998045755-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE]"
Feb 07 18:20:26 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:26.999890769-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.001411556-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -I DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.002796387-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.005507596-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.007945397-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.009553277-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.011134636-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.012863616-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.014507969-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.016206339-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.017849596-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.019419670-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.021080108-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.022686053-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.024285206-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.031344452-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.038642024-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.040342056-05:00" level=debug msg="/sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION]"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.052652239-05:00" level=debug msg="Starting container a1f4d5471b0aaa56df52dda1253cb325477f8f83e7f41a5441b64384d4750471"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.061762755-05:00" level=debug msg="container mounted via layerStore: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3d26a41419b24a29c56cb045fc3e36377f612ae4afe72e4bec71d5b621be1098/merged"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.062039104-05:00" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint db-mysql's interface on network bridge"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.062068648-05:00" level=debug msg="RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, <nil>, map[])"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.073698920-05:00" level=debug msg="Assigning addresses for endpoint db-mysql's interface on network bridge"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.133676914-05:00" level=debug msg="Releasing addresses for endpoint db-mysql's interface on network bridge"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.133709009-05:00" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.2)"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.140074937-05:00" level=warning msg="error locating sandbox id 3379ca22818f326ee78d83327c1a927ff9c10862b24d051eddda3455cddf63a7: sandbox 3379ca22818f326ee78d83327c1a927ff9c10862b24d051eddda3455cddf63a7 not found"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.140156532-05:00" level=warning msg="failed to cleanup ipc mounts:\nfailed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/a1f4d5471b0aaa56df52dda1253cb325477f8f83e7f41a5441b64384d4750471/shm: invalid argument"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.159819035-05:00" level=error msg="Failed to start container a1f4d5471b0aaa56df52dda1253cb325477f8f83e7f41a5441b64384d4750471: open /etc/resolv.conf: no such file or directory"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.159867740-05:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.206574056-05:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.207257097-05:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=49bf474 graphdriver=overlay2 version=1.13.0
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.207778425-05:00" level=debug msg="Registering routers"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.208066178-05:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/checkpoints"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.208270977-05:00" level=debug msg="Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/checkpoints"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.208363039-05:00" level=debug msg="Registering DELETE, /containers/{name}/checkpoints/{checkpoint}"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.208496291-05:00" level=debug msg="Registering HEAD, /containers/{name:.*}/archive"
Feb 07 18:20:27 DebianV dockerd[641]: time="2017-02-07T05:20:27.208638014-05:00" level=debug msg="Registering GET, /containers/json"
```

add the docker ps -a message, 
    $ docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
    a1f4d5471b0a        mysql:8.0           "docker-entrypoint..."   15 hours ago        Exited (128) 17 minutes ago                       db-mysql
    20b7feb5fd9f        hello-world         "/hello"                 16 hours ago        Exited (0) 16 hours ago                           youthful_golick

i user '$ docker logs db-mysql' to show the container last log time, it's not change after reboot. so i think it's not the condition of container started after reboot, and then exit later

Comment: It's highly likely that your container did start but exited unexpectedly. If that's the case, the container logs would be more interesting than the daemon's ones.

Comment: The output of `docker ps` and/or `docker ps -a` after the reboot might be interesting as well.

Comment: thanks for answer!  i test the condition of container started after reboot, and exited later for some reson. i think it's not this condition.

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved.  it is caused by the missing of /etc/resolv.conf during the docker start.

docker daemon try to start container, but it cannot find the file /etc/resolv.conf, so failed.

/etc/reslv.conf is a link file to /var/run/NetworkManger/resolv.conf.
in my os, /etc/resolv.conf will be updated by the NetworkManager, because it is not static ip, so ,before i login and connect to network, this file does not exist!

i change the config of NetworkManger in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, set the 'dns=none' in [main] area, so it stop modify resolv.conf. 
at the same time remove the link file /etc/resolv.conf, add a new file for /etc/resolv.conf, like 'nameserver=8.8.8.8'

after reboot, the docker container can autostart, works fine!